# Pandas dataframe split based on a filter on groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe like below

[image]

I want to split the dataframe and create two separate dataframes based on whether I have a unique group of `'O', 'A', 'N', 'value_next'` or not. So I did this:

```
mask = dft.groupby(['O', 'A', 'N', 'value_next']).filter(lambda x: len(x) <= 1)

df1 = dft[mask]
df2 = dft[~mask]
```

But the line `df1 = dft[mask]`

gives error

```
ValueError: Boolean array expected for the condition, not int64
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `filter` returns a dataframe, not an index/mask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a slightly different approach using `.duplicated` instead of groupby/filter which can be really slow if you have a large dft. Note `keep=False` which marks all duplicate rows, instead of ignoring the first instance of a duplicate which is default behavior

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

num_rows = 100

np.random.seed(1)

#Creating a test df
dft = pd.DataFrame({
    'time':np.random.randint(5,25,num_rows),
    'O':np.random.randint(1,4,num_rows),
    'A':np.random.randint(1,4,num_rows),
    'N':np.random.randint(1,4,num_rows),
    'value':np.random.randint(10,100,num_rows),
    'value_next':np.random.randint(-10,40,num_rows),
})

#Getting a mask of True if duplicated, False otherwise
is_dup = dft.duplicated(['O', 'A', 'N', 'value_next'],keep=False)

df1 = dft[~is_dup]
df2 = dft[is_dup]

print(df2)

#Quick check that a row in df2 was originally duplicated
dft[
    dft['O'].eq(2) &
    dft['A'].eq(3) &
    dft['N'].eq(1) &
    dft['value_next'].eq(8)
]
```

Comment: This works but I do not understand what does `2` mean in dft['O'].eq(2) and similar

Comment: It's shorthand for `dft[(dft['O'] == 2) & (dft['A'] == 3) & ...`. I was just finding all rows that matched all these criteria to make sure the duplication finding was working